# How to Save the Repeatable fields data in Reusable Custom box WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

hello I am using reusable custom metaboxes from https://github.com/tammyhart/Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes.. 
these are my fields

```
array( 
    'label' => __('Setup Slider', 'crispy' ), 
    'desc'  => __('create your slider image/ text using these repeatable options', 'crispy' ), 
    'id'    => $prefix.'repeatable', 
    'type'  => 'repeatable',
    'sanitizer' => array( 
        'title' => 'sanitize_text_field',
        'desc' => 'wp_kses_data'
    ),
    'repeatable_fields' => array ( 
        array( 
            'label' => __(' Slider Text alignment', 'crispy'),
            'id'    => 'alignment',
            'type'  => 'radio',
            'options' => array (
                'one' => array ( 
                    'label' => __('Left', 'crispy' ), 
                    'value' => 'left' 
                ),
                'two' => array (
                    'label' => __('Center', 'crispy' ),
                    'value' => 'center'
                ),
                'three' => array (
                    'label' => __('Right', 'crispy' ),
                    'value' => 'right'
                )
            )
        ),

        array( 
            'label' => __('Background Image/pattern', 'crispy' ), 
            'id'    => 'image', 
            'type'  => 'image'
        ),              

        array(
            'label' => __('Title', 'crispy' ),
            'id' => 'title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),  

        array(
            'label' => __('Description', 'crispy' ),
            'id' => 'desc',
            'type' => 'textarea'
        ),          


    )
),
```

My problem is i don't know how to store the fields value... can anyone resolve my problem!!..

```
$home_slider_alignment = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'alignment', true);
```

i used this but doesn't help!!.. Those fields can be repeatable so the values are stored in array!!.. i don't know how to retrieve stored values from that array??..

Please help me!!.

Answer (score 0):

It is working :)

```
enter code here
<?php
    $projectgallery = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'arcadia_well_projectgallery', true); {
    echo '<ul class="custom_repeatable">';
    foreach ($projectgallery as $project) {
        echo '<li>';
        foreach($project as $i=>$value) {
            echo $value;
        }
        echo '</li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
```